# Linksys AE1200 doesn't work with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, usb, broadcom

I have read through and followed several different posts on this topic, including trying ndiswrapper.  Nothing seems to get this USB wireless adapter working for me.  I need an expert to help walk me through it.

```
mark@mark-Studio:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 058f:6363 Alcor Micro Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 18d1:4ee1 Google Inc. Nexus 4
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 0461:4d64 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13b1:0039 Linksys AE1200 802.11bgn Wireless Adapter [Broadcom BCM43235]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
mark@mark-Studio:~$ ndiswrapper -l
bcmwlhigh6 : driver installed
    device (13B1:0039) present
mark@mark-Studio:~$
```

Here's the dmeg stuff...

```
mark@mark-Studio:~$ dmesg | grep ndis
[   22.443197] ndiswrapper: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   22.444103] ndiswrapper version 1.59 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
[   22.678387] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
[127938.097580] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateIoWorkItem'
[127938.097589] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisQueueIoWorkItem'
[127938.097593] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMSendNetBufferListsComplete'
[127938.097598] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists'
[127938.097602] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeIoWorkItem'
[127938.097606] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMSetMiniportAttributes'
[127938.097612] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMDeregisterMiniportDriver'
[127938.097616] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMResetComplete'
[127938.097620] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMPauseComplete'
[127938.097624] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateNetBufferListPool'
[127938.097632] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMOidRequestComplete'
[127938.097636] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeNetBufferListPool'
[127938.097640] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMRegisterMiniportDriver'
[127938.097644] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisOpenConfigurationEx'
[127938.097648] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisSetTimerObject'
[127938.097653] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateTimerObject'
[127938.097658] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisCancelTimerObject'
[127938.097662] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeNetBufferList'
[127938.097666] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMIndicateStatusEx'
[127938.097672] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisGetSystemUpTimeEx'
[127938.097676] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateNetBufferAndNetBufferList'
[127938.097680] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateMdl'
[127938.097684] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeMdl'
[127938.097692] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMGetBusData'
[127938.097703] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeTimerObject'
[127938.097708] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateMemoryWithTagPriority'
[127938.097713] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: WDFLDR.SYS:'WdfVersionBind'
[127938.097717] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: WDFLDR.SYS:'WdfVersionUnbind'
[127938.097719] ndiswrapper (load_sys_files:200): couldn't prepare driver 'bcmwlhigh6'
[127938.098347] ndiswrapper (load_wrap_driver:103): couldn't load driver bcmwlhigh6; check system log for messages from 'loadndisdriver'
mark@mark-Studio:~$
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `lsusb` and also: `ndiswrapper -l`. Thanks.

Comment: I've added the output

Comment: Looks just fine so far! Please add: `dmesg | grep ndis`. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it looked fine too... but this new stuff looks bad - let me know what's missing here, please!  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that you used Windows *XP* driver files. ndiswrapper requires XP. From `man ndiswrapper-1.9`:

> DESCRIPTION
>          ndiswrapper is two parts: user space tool that is used to install  Windows  XP drivers and kernel module to load the Windows XP
>   drivers. Both
>          are called ndiswrapper.

Is there also a file bcmwlhigh5.inf in the folder? I suggest you remove 6 and try 5:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -e bcmwlhigh6
sudo ndiswrapper -i /path/to/folder/bcmwlhigh5.inf
```

Reboot and check:

```
dmesg | grep ndis
iwconfig
```

If this method still produces errors in `dmesg` and no working wireless, I suggest you try the driver files from here: http://wikidevi.com/files/Drivers/Broadcom/bcm4323x_5.100.68.46_XP.zip and, if still not working, from here: http://wikidevi.com/files/Drivers/Broadcom/bcm4323x_6.30.145.26_XP.zip

In each trial, erase the previously defective driver files:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -e bcmwlhigh5
sudo rm -rf /etc/ndiswrapper/*
```

Then install the newer driver files as I described above. Then test:

```
ndiswrapper -l
```

That is a lower-case L for 'list'. It should report that the driver is loaded *AND* that the corresponding device is present. If so, then:

```
sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
dmesg | grep ndis
iwconfig
```

If you have lengthy log files to show us, please post them here http://paste.ubuntu.com and give us the link.

Comment: I had tried to use the Win XP driver (the high5 version), but ndiswrapper said that the hardware was not installed and put a big red "X" over it.  The Vista driver is the only one which didn't give me the red "X".  I am using the GUI for ndiswrapper though.

Comment: 'code'mark@mark-Studio:~$ sudo ndiswrapper -e bcmwlhigh6
[sudo] password for mark: 
no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory
mark@mark-Studio:~$ sudo ndiswrapper -i linksys-usb/xp/bcmwlhigh5.inf 
installing bcmwlhigh5 ...
couldn't find section "Linksys_AE1200.files.NTamd64" -
installation may be incomplete
couldn't find section "Linksys_AE2500.files.NTamd64" -
installation may be incomplete
'code'

Comment: mark@mark-Studio:~$ dmesg | grep ndis
[   11.479907] ndiswrapper: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   11.480767] ndiswrapper version 1.59 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
[   11.915929] ndiswrapper (load_wrap_driver:103): couldn't load driver bcmwlhigh5; check system log for messages from 'loadndisdriver'
[   11.916025] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper

Comment: mark@mark-Studio:~$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

Comment: What does the syslog report? `cat /var/log/syslog | grep ndis` Since the output may be lengthy, please post it here and give us a link: http://paste.ubuntu.com  Can you confirm you used _XP_ drivers?

Comment: I used the driver from the xp folder.  There is no output from syslog using the command you provided above.

Comment: I tried a sudo cat and did get this one line:

Comment: mark@mark-Studio:~$ sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep ndis
[sudo] password for mark: 
no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory

Comment: `syslog` fills up, is archived and starts over. Please try: `cat /var/log/syslog.1 | grep ndis` Thanks.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11753456/

Comment: Please don't give up! :)

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Tried both drivers you suggest above.  Both work just as good as the one on the CD (that is... they don't).  Here's the terminal output:

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11770978/

Comment: I don't know if I mentioned this before, but my machine is dual boot with Windows Vista and the thing does definitely work in Vista, so I don't think it is a hardware problem.

Comment: Ok, so I rebooted my machine, just to see if that would do anything.... and yes, the blue light came on!  But I cannot connect to my wireless network for some reason.  Here's the output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11771618/

Comment: Looks much better. Does it try to connect? Does it scan and see networks?  `sudo iwlist wlan2 scan` Why is it wlan2? Is there another wireless device present that may be conflicting? Is there any clue in the log? `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e etwork -e wlan | tail -n20` Please paste as before.

Comment: Here's the output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11776859/

Comment: I did have another USB wireless antenna thing that I had been using, but it stopped working after it got physically damaged.  Hence why I bought the new Linksys.

Comment: And yes, it does scan and show me networks.  I just doesn't connect to my wireless network.  Asks for password, but never actually connects.

Comment: Your log shows the ethernet connecting perfectly and nothing at all about wireless. Please detach the ethernet and try again.

Comment: sorry!  Disconnected the ethernet cable and here's the output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11785755/